# How do you say "You can't automatize a mess"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, phrase, phrase-request

I don't know if phrase translation requests are on-topic but I would really like to know is there's a way to convey this meaning in Latin:

> "You can't automatize a mess" or "Disorder cannot be automatized".

This mean that in order to automatize a process you should first bring order to said process, otherwise you wouldn't have clear rules for an automaton/machine/software to perform tasks.

I know the verb *automatize* is modern but the word *automaton* is not. That may be of help. I would prefer the Latin equivalent to *mess* since it has the informal spirit of the original phrase.

In the worst case scenario an equivalent known proverb that conveys the same meaning could be useful.

Comment: Welcome! I edited your question slightly; feel free to re-edit or roll back. Asking for translations is on-topic. See [these guidelines](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/143/79) about asking such questions for details.

Comment: What's *automatize*? Do you mean *automate*?

Comment: @andy256 Look at this: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/automatize

Comment: Why add an extra syllable to a word, and then say it had the same meaning as the old word?

Comment: @andy256 I didn't invent the word as you can see in the dictionary entry. Feel free to edit the question and chance it to automate, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest:

> Chaos in automatum non reducitur.

A literal translation is "Chaos is not reduced to an automaton", i.e. "cannot be brought into the condition of something that works automatically". As Joonas Ilmavirta says, it's hard to a find a Latin verb meaning "automatize". A workaround is to use a phrase like "reduce to an automaton, bring into the state of an automaton"; this is what I used above, but in the passive. *Chaos* is originally a Greek word, but was widely used in Latin; Ovid (*Metamorphoses* book 1) describes the creation of the ordered world out of primeval chaos. As a word for the ultimate state of lack of order, it seems to be appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a classical Latin word for "automatize", and I don't think using only classical words to say something along the lines of "to turn something into a self-moving machine" would do any good here.
Therefore I suggest using the verb *automatizare* for "to automatize".
I do not recall ever seeing this verb, but it should be easy enough to understand, given the analogous words in other languages and the natural Latin derivation *automatum/automaton* + *-izare*.

For "mess" I suggest
[*confusio*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2012773),
[*turba*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2061161) or
[*perturbatio*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2044298).
Check the English translations of those words and choose what fits your intention.
Or find a new word altogether; I'm not entirely satisfied with these words, but I can't think of better ones.
We have a list of online dictionaries [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).

With these ingredients I suggest:

> *Confusio automatizari non potest.*
>   Disorder cannot be automatized.

Comment: How about *"an automaton cannot help you do your work when things are in disarray"*?

Comment: @user679 Perhaps *automaton in confusione non fungitur*, "an automaton doesn't work in disorder"? Or *automaton in confusione opus non facit*, "an automaton doesn't do work in disorder"? Or if you want it longer, perhaps *automaton in operando auxiliari non potest cum res in confusione sint*, "an automaton cannot help in working when things are in disorder".

Comment: How about (going off your last comment) *Automaton ex confusione non oritur* (or *non factum est* or something of the sort)?

Comment: @JoelDerfner, good idea. Maybe we could go as far as *confusio automaton non fit*, "disorder does not become an automaton".